# Имеется список целых чисел Измените исходный список, вставив элемент со значением k между всеми соседними элементами списка, имеющими одинаковый знак

Tags: python, list

Имеется список целых чисел. Измените исходный список, вставив элемент со значением **k** между всеми соседними элементами исходного списка, имеющими одинаковый знак. Считать, что 0 имеет общий со своими соседями знак.

**Формат входных данных**

> В первой строке вводится последовательность целых чисел через пробел – элементы списка.
> Во второй строке вводится целое число **k**.

**Формат выходных данных**

> Требуется вывести измененный список.

**входные данные**

1 0 9 4 2 9
55

**выходные данные**

1 55 0 55 9 55 4 55 2 55 9

**входные данные**

1 -10 -10 3 -5 0 -1 5 9 10
55

**выходные данные**

1 -10 55 -10 3 -5 55 0

**Мой код:**

```
s=list(map(int,input().split()))
k=int(input())
i=0
while i<len(s):
    if s[i]>0 and s[i+1]>0:
        s[i+2]=s[i+1]
        s[i+1]=k
    elif s[i]<0 and s[i+1]<0:
        s[i+2]=s[i+1]
        s[i+1]=k
    else:
        i+=1
    print(*s)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Твоя проблема в том, что ты работя с одним и тем же списком и добавляя элемент в него не сдвигаешь все остальные элементы назад. На твоем месте я бы не трогал исходный список а пытался сформировать новый в который попадут элементы старого списка + элемент `k` по мере необходимости

например так:

```
input_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
k = int(input())
i = 0
result_list = []
result_list.append(input_list[0])  
for current_element in input_list[1:]:
    if any((
            current_element > 0 and result_list[-1] > 0,
            current_element < 0 and result_list[-1] < 0,
            current_element == 0 or result_list[-1] == 0
    )):  # нужно между элементами вставить k. 
        result_list.append(k)
    result_list.append(current_element)
print(result_list)
```

условие внутри `if` можно упростить на `current_element * result_list[-1] >= 0`

у тебя, ктати, второй пример имеет некорректный вывод (результат короче исходного списка)

П.с.: при выборе названий для переменных не экономь буквы, называй их как-то осмысленно, чтобы легче было читать твой код